# Installing C++ compiler at terminal on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I wanted to install a C++ compiler on my computer in Linux and I used fallowing code in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

After that, the terminal wanted password from me, but when I typed the password I saw this error:

```
Sorry, Try again!
```

My password wasn't wrong!

Comment: I think your password is wrong. But you dont know its wrong.

Comment: What distribution are you using?  Do you know whether you have it set to ask for the root or user passwords?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** If you're typing a password in the command line, no characters will appear; this way, if people are standing behind you, they will not see your password. That seems to have been the misunderstanding here. Just type the full password and hit enter, it should work.

Are you typing the password for root, or the password for your user account?

Try hitting ctrl+alt+F1, logging in as root, and typing

```
passwd <your_user_name>
```

then changing the password.

You **are** typing in the wrong password for the account you're trying to use, so either you need to change that account's password, or you need to figure out which account it is and use the correct one.

P.S.: check capslock. Silly as it is, there's a reason people say it.

Comment: MY account and my password are correct.but when I hit any key in front of password.my computer didnt work!!!!and I could not type my password...and said login is incorrect

Comment: When you type a password in the command line, no characters appear. This way, someone looking over your shoulder cannot see what your password is. Just type your password and hit enter - it should work.

Comment: If someone's comment fixes your problem, make sure to mark it as correct! This way, anyone else with the same problem will see the solution. Happy to hear it's been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume you have rootpw off, so it wants your user password.  To reset a user password, follow [these steps](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword).  In summary:

1. Reboot
2. When GRUB comes up, choose an entry that includes "(recovery mode)"
3. Choose "Drop to root shell prompt"
4. Run `passwd yourUsername`, and follow the prompts.
5. Run `exit`.
6. Choose "resume normal boot".

If it were the root password, you could run `passwd root` instead.